# Sonar for CSharp with Ant task not working

Tags: c#, batch-file, ant, sonarqube

I am new to Sonar and ANT scripts. After lot of struggle, I structured the xmls and other files for sonar/ant.

The Dotnetbuild.xml, which is placed in a folder called deploy where a1.sln has relative path. And is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="DotNetBuild">
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="a1" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="a1" />
<property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
<property name="sonar.language" value="cs" />
<property name="sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file" value="Projects\a1\RSourceCode\a1\a1.sln" />
<property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:9000/" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="sonar" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="sonar" />   
<target name="sonar">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" />
    <sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant" />
</target>
</project>
```

I'm having another batch file called buildit.bat with

```
set ANT_HOME=D:\Softwares\ant
set ANT_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Xms128M -Xmx512M
set path=%path%;%ANT_HOME%\bin    
ant -f DotNetbuild.xml
```

Points of interest: ANT installed at D:\Softwares\Ant.

Sonar is installed on desktop (Windows) and it is started and running.

Have the sonar extension plugins for dotnet installed sonar-3.6\extensions\plugins folder.

A missing lib ant-contrib-0.6 is installed in D:\Softwares\ant\lib folder

When I run the batch file, it says Build successful, Total Time: 0 seconds. But when I refresh Sonar URL, there is nothing relevant to a1 project.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified a target to run:

```
..
ant -f DotNetbuild.xml sonar
```

The default target could be specified at the top of your build file:

```
<project name="DotNetBuild" default="sonar">
..
..
```

### Related

Why ANT? The Sonarqube document recommends using the java runner:

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Running+an+Analysis+on+a+C%23+Solution

Might be simpler than setting up an alternative build tool.

### Misc

You don't need the "ant-contrib" jar to run Sonar. What you will need is the Sonar ANT task jar.